# JavaMe: Random number generation of 14 positive digits

Tags: java, java-me, jakarta-ee

I want to generate a random number of 14 positive digits only and I use the below function for it:

```
public void random()
{
  Random number = new Random();
  long l = number.nextLong();
  number.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());    

  long num = Math.abs(number.nextInt())%999 + (l/100000); // problematic line
  mTextBox.setString("" + num);
}
```

I very new to to JavaMe, I have made above function myself but I believe it is not working as expected. It also generates -ve numbers. Also sometimes one or two digits are missing in generated number resulting in 12 or 13 numbers not 14.

Any suggestions or improvement to the code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've only just noticed you asked the same question on January 16th. *Please* don't ask duplicated like this.

Comment: @Jon: Sir previsouly i  had asked how to generate random number, now i am asking how to avoid -ve numbers and generate only 14 digits. Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz: From your previous question: "Basically i want to generate a 14 digits random number". In what way is that *not* asking how to generate 14 digits?

Comment: @Sarfraz: So edit the question to give more details, comment on the answers etc. Don't just abandon it and ask again.

Comment: @Skeet: I thought i won't get new answers, ideas, suggestion to already asked question. Thanks for letting me know that even that works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 14 digits, then you should use 14 calls to `number.nextInt(10)` - something like this:

```
public static String randomDigits(Random random, int length)
{
    char[] digits = new char[length];
    // Make sure the leading digit isn't 0.
    digits[0] = (char)('1' + random.nextInt(9);
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        digits[i] = (char)('0' + random.nextInt(10));
    }
    return new String(digits);
}
```

Note that I've made the instance of `Random` something you pass in, rather than created by the method - this makes it easier to use *one* instance and avoid duplicate seeding. It's also more general purpose, as it separates the "use the string in the UI" aspect from the "generate a random string of digits".

I don't know whether `Random.nextInt(int)` is supported on J2ME - let me know if it's not. Using `Math.abs(number.nextInt())%999` is a bad idea in terms of random distributions.

Comment: Shouldn't the first digit be between 1 and 9?

Comment: @uncleo: I've mentioned this in an edit - it depends on whether it's meant to be treated as a *number* or just a sequence of 14 digits. It's easy enough to fix if necessary.

Comment: @Sarfraz: We're only generating digits, so how could it possibly generate a negative number? Will edit for avoiding the leading zero.

Comment: @Skeet: Thanks man for your help, i have implemented it, it is working fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand what you really want, the code suggests that you want a 3 digit number (`%999`).
Otherwise you can create a 14 digit number between 1000000000000000 and 9999999999999999 by

```
long num = 1000000000000000L + (long)(number.nextDouble() * 8999999999999999.0);
```

*note `(1 / 100000)` is 0 (zero) since it is done by integer division, use `(1.0 / 100000.0)` for double division*

Answer (score 1):

```
long num = 10000000000000L+(long)(random.nextDouble()*90000000000000.0);
```

EDIT:

```
mTextBox.setString(MessageFormat.format("{0,number,00000000000000}",
    new Object[] {new Long(num)}));
```

Comment: There's absolutely no guarantee that'll produce a 14 digit number. What if nextDouble returns 0?

Comment: I think nextDouble is not supported in j2me

Comment: @Jon Skeet: this is a formatting problem, @Sarfraz Ahmed: it is in CLDC 1.1

Comment: At that point you've got the same problem as my original answer did, of having leading zeroes. I would also be somewhat concerned about the distribution of the later digits. It just seems a fairly roundabout way of doing it - Sarfraz wants 14 digits, so why not just generate 14 digits?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting negative numbers because `Random.nextInt()` returns *any* 32-bit integer, and half of them are negative. If you want to get only positive numbers, you should use the expression `Random.nextInt() & 0x7fffffff` or simply `Random.nextInt(10)` for a digit.